# Can I use dbms_random.string to generate a random value between two string options in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a people table with two fields (id, gender). Most of my gender values are either 'M' or 'F', but there are some 'N' and some nulls. Fixing these bad values is not an option, but I still need to account for them in a query. I am trying to randomly assign the 'N' & null values to either 'M' or 'F'. The query I have below seems like it should work, but it gives me a **ORA-01722: invalid number** error. I also tried wrapping both sides of the WHEN line in to_char, but get the same error. Does the dbms_random function have to use numbers?

I can do a subquery that assigns them to either 1 or 2, and then an outer query to convert them to either M or F, but would rather not if I can just do it in one statement.

```
select id,
    gender,
    case 
        when nvl(gender, 'N') = 'N' then dbms_random.string('M', 'F')
        else gender
     end as gender_new             
from people;
```

Comment: If any "random" assignment will work for whatever problem you are trying to solve, then wouldn't a deterministic one work as well? (If not, why not?) What I suggest is map all 'N' to 'M' and all null to 'F', and be done with it. How important is "randomness" here?

Comment: I have 800 nulls and 100 N's. I am supposed to group all of these together and then randomize them into either M or F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select decode(round(dbms_random.value), 1, 'F', 'M') rnd
from dual
connect by level <= 10;

R
-
F
F
F
F
M
M
F
F
M
F

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle function `DBMS_RANDOM.STRING()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS67503) does not work like you expect. As arguments, it takes a format specifier and a number that represents the expected length of the output string (you are getting an error because the second argument that you are giving, `F`, is not a number). You cannot specify a list of strings to pick from.

To generate a random distribution between two values, you could use `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()` to generate a random decimal value between `0` and `1` and interpret the result in a `CASE` expression, like:

```
CASE WHEN DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() < 0.5 THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END
```

**[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3e113c5385c972b8cb69b50f04f8e506)**:

```
WITH tries AS (SELECT ROWNUM rn FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 5)   
SELECT CASE WHEN DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() < 0.5 THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END AS gender FROM tries
```

```
| GENDER |
| :----- |
| M      |
| M      |
| F      |
| M      |
| M      |
```